# Make a frame to an image in Julia

Tags: image, julia

Images are represented as matrices. Is there a practical way to make sort of frame around the content of the image? (in a monoton color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Images, TestImages, Colors

img = testimage("mandrill")

padarray(img, Fill(colorant"magenta", (40, 40), (40, 40)))
```

[image: magenta mandrill1]

#### Update

I don't understand your comment - but you might be asking how you can use this padded image as a normal image? One way is `parent`.

```
img_with_pretty_frame = 
    padarray(img, Fill(colorant"magenta", (40, 40), (40, 40)))

w, h = size(img_with_pretty_frame)

img2 = parent(img_with_pretty_frame)

img2[w ÷ 2 - 100:w ÷ 2 + 100, h÷2 - 200:h÷2 + 200] .= colorant"blue"

img2
```

[image: mod mandrill]

Comment: I tried accessing the image with [x,y] indexing, but it seems that this way only the original image touched. Is it possible to have this framed image in the same format as the original? (to be able to use the [x,y] indexing in the same way) Thanks in advance!